# WebStorm velocity template engine

Tags: javascript, velocity, webstorm

I have trouble creating a JavaScript template in WebStorm, which is using velocity template engine.

The final document I am trying to get looks like this:

```
app.service('Name', ['$http', function($http) {
 var singularUrlbase = apiurl + 'SingularName';
 var pluralUrlbase = apiurl + 'PluralName';

 this.get = function(id){
   return $http.get( singularUrlBase + id );
 } 
}
```

I am trying with this template:

```
#set ( $url1 = 'singularUrlBase + "/" + id')
#set ( $url2 = "singularUrlBase + '/' + s.Id")

app.service('${NAME}', ['$http', function($http) {

    var pluralUrlBase = apiurl + '$pluralName';
    var singularUrlBase = apiurl + '$singularName';

    this.get = function(id) {                        
        return $http.get( $url1 );
    };
}
```

The problems are:

- It displays `return $http.get ( $url1 )` instead of `return $http.get( singularUrlBase + id );`
- I don't know how to ignore `$http`, WebStorm is asking me to setup $http variable, but I don't want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape a `$` symbol in jetbrains apps templates, you need to write `${DS}` as shown in the [docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html)

### template code

Should look like this:

```
#set ( $url1 = 'singularUrlBase + "/" + id')
#set ( $url2 = 'pluralUrlBase + "/" + id')

app.service('${NAME}', ['${DS}http', function(${DS}http) {

    var pluralUrlBase = apiurl + '$pluralName';
    var singularUrlBase = apiurl + '$singularName';

    this.get = function(id) {
        if (this.get > 1) {
            return ${DS}http.get( $url1 );
        }
        else {
            return ${DS}http.get( $url2 );
        }
    }
}]);
```

### inputs

file name: `young_people`
pluralName: `child`
singularName: `children`

### result:

```
app.service('young_people', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var pluralUrlBase = apiurl + 'child';
    var singularUrlBase = apiurl + 'children';

    this.get = function (id) {
        if (this.get > 1) {
            return $http.get(singularUrlBase + "/" + id);
        }
        else {
            return $http.get(pluralUrlBase + "/" + id);
        }
    }
}]);
```

*Note: your syntax was a bit wrong, I fixed the two last lines ;).*

Comment: Thanks. The problem with the '+' is that it crashes the template engine.
That's the reason why I used ; #set ( $url1 = 'singularUrlBase + "/" + id'). But this trick doesn't work.

Comment: I see, I just updated my code, figured out I pasted wrong code for template (need some coffee). you were not using `$url2` in your question, I think `$url1 = 'singularUrlBase + "/" + id')` is ok, but you should manually add `s` to plural name because of english exceptions with pluran names ;). I don't have any problem here with `'+'`, did not play much with template files, answered a bit too quick, but it seems to work here.